# Installing docker on Ubuntu 16.04 disconnects the internet and intranet

Tags: docker

I installed docker on my laptop having ubuntu 16.04, it started a new network bridge connection called docker0 and all my net connection including internet and intranet stopped working.
Tried many many things which found through google but none of them worked.
Surprisingly the same docker installation on Linux desktop having ubuntu 16.04 didnt stop the internet. Same steps were followed.

Please let me know if any of you know what can be causing this.

Regards,
DK

Comment: Have you taken a look at your ifconfig if there is an ip address on your network connections?

Comment: I do see a new network connection by the name docker0, this connection goes once I delete this connection from the frontend.